# How is the virtual address of the page table is converted to its actual physical address?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, paging

If paging is enabled in OS, a page table is used to map the virtual address to the actual physical address. To be more specific, consider Linux 32 bit OS on X86, the cr3 register has the starting address of the page table directory. I guess this is a virtual address. How will the CPU maps this virtual address to the physical address of the page table directory on RAM.
Which page table will be used for this address translation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, cr3 has the physical address of page table, not the virtual address. If cr3 contains the virtual address of page table, you'll fall into a logic dead loop and have no way to find page table.

Answer (score 0):

The paging unit translates linear addresses into physical ones.
Set of linear addresses are grouped together to form a page. These linear addresses are continuous in nature - the paging unit maps these sets of contiguous memory to corresponding set of contiguous physical addresses called page frames. Please note that the paging unit is divided into RAM page frames of fixed size. For this reason, the pagination has the following advantages:

- Permissions defined for the page will be valid for a group of linear addresses forming a page
- The page length is the length of the page frame

The data structure that maps these pages to page frames, called a page table. These page tables are stored in main memory and the kernel is initialized before the resolution of the module management pages.

[see to the link](https://www.google.pl/search?sa=G&q=logical%20address%20and%20physical%20address&tbm=isch&imgil=EpD9GF-JZc3UzM%253A%253BuhL8zNoxczTu2M%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.ksyash.com%25252F2011%25252F01%25252Fmemory-byte-reading-writing%25252F&source=iu&pf=m&tbs=simg:CAES0QEazgELEKjU2AQaAggKDAsQsIynCBpgCl4IAxIo7AffE-AT3hPrAt0T6weDE8YThBPTNqg-pz7HNsw_1zT_1yP5Q3qj7PPxowU3jsb7D8LnLFBsyCRYFLwNlsJTCyvulFVim_16Gttilo3jr9GEErX1ds2BOk07yLZDAsQjq7-CBoKCggIARIExj5k5wwLEJ3twQkaPgoJCgdkcmF3aW5nCgkKB2RpYWdyYW0KEwoRdGVjaG5pY2FsIGRyYXdpbmcKCQoHYXJ0d29yawoGCgRhcmVhDA&fir=EpD9GF-JZc3UzM%253A%252CuhL8zNoxczTu2M%252C_&usg=__ToioORGyUjytpvNEsqaVVWRlrXE%3D&biw=1745&bih=908&ved=0CD8Qyjc&ei=wc8BVa22KoStabyrgPAP&qscrl=1#imgdii=_&imgrc=EpD9GF-JZc3UzM%253A%3BuhL8zNoxczTu2M%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.ksyash.com%252Fwp-content%252Fuploads%252F2011%252F01%252Fmemory-byte-reading-writing_img21.png%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.ksyash.com%252F2011%252F01%252Fmemory-byte-reading-writing%252F%3B400%3B323)